# ROS Answers SE migration: Gmapping path

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a hokuyo laser scanner and odometry with Gmapping to generate a map. The problem is that i need to have the path of which the robot has taken when recording the map.

I have cameras attached to it, which takes pictures which i transform to panorama pictures, and i need them to be on the map at the exact position they were taken.

I am using time as an indicator of when the pictures were taken and i would like to compare the coordinates of the robot with the time.

ps. i am new to Ros answers, please tell me if i need to include code/information/etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71002/gmapping-path/) by [Kax](https://answers.ros.org/users/5749/kax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please make sure you don't miss any [ROS tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) thats relevant to you. Including those concepts at the bottom. For you most important is the [tf concept](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/).

Basically your camera has to be set a coordinate frame that is included in its image message's header, along with the timestamp. Then any node can ask the `tf` system what offset that frame had in respect to another (e.g. /map) for any given time (though I don't know the default history length).

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1